# website displaying wrong timezone

Tags: php, wordpress, ubuntu, nginx, timezone

I been breaking my brain about this one…

- **Server Location:** San Francisco
- **Server Configuration:** Ubuntu + LEMP
- **App:** Wordpress

Ok so I set Ubuntu's time to my current time and changed the time zone to HST which is the one Im at and restarted cron.

I set the php.ini timezone to Pacific/Honolulu and set Wordpress Settings/Timezone to Pacific/Honolulu

Restarted nginx and php...

However when I

`<?php echo date('e'); ?>`

it displays **UTC**…

am I missing anything? help!

Comment: Where is ubuntu system  ?

Comment: Server time could be set incorrectly. Is this your server, shared, etc;

Comment: Have you done
date_default_timezone_set('HNL');  // or whatever the timezone designation is

Answer (score 1):

Try following,

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');
echo date_default_timezone_get() . ' => ' . date('e') . ' => ' . date('T');
?>
```

Comment: I tried that and it works, however I can't figure it out why it shows UTC when, ubuntu, php and wordpress are set to HST

Answer (score 0):

Set the timzone within the script.

```
date_default_timezone_set('PST');
date('e');
```

Answer (score 0):

What was your system timezone set to when you've originally started nginx?

Did you actually shutdown `nginx`, and then started it up from scratch, or did you simply made it re-read its configuration file?  (FYI: the popular `cat /var/run/nginx.pid | xargs kill -HUP` would not result in a restart.)

Your best bet would probably be to do something like `sudo sh -c "cat /usr/share/zoneinfo/Pacific/Honolulu > /etc/localtime"`, remove any timezone mentions from the individual apps, and then properly shutdown and startup the whole server.

Answer (score 0):

In your `php.ini` file make sure you set:

`date.timezone = "America/Los_Angeles"`

And then change your server time to the appropriate timezone using:

`sudo dpkg-reconfigure tzdata`

Answer (score 0):

Better late than never, so I'll chime in here. It's actually WordPress and the weird decision to set the default timezone back to UTC no matter what your INI settings might be. This delightful gem can be found in [wp-settings.php](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/src/wp-settings.php#L43) (link is for trunk version, marked line might be off in the future).

I guess they did it to keep their internal time calculations easy and on a common base. I do understand the intention behind this but still think it's awkward and surely has caused lots of confusion and trouble for users and developers (like me just now). They could've kept it internal.

Anyways, the bottom line is: When doing your own time calculations in a theme or plug-in or whatever, be sure to explicitly set the timezone beforehand.

Just using `time()` and thinking you're good to go might lead to headaches. You can get what is set in the settings panel via `get_option('timezone_string')` and for example use that in conjunction with `date_default_timezone_set`.

Weston Ruter [summed this all up just fine](https://weston.ruter.net/2013/04/02/do-not-change-the-default-timezone-from-utc-in-wordpress/) and also suggests using PHP's date and time related classes and explicitly setting the timezone for them.